Update new navigation arguments to the composable view when the compose navigation action is set to restore previous state
The composable view is not getting updated with new arguments that are passed through deep link when the navigation action is launched as single-top and state is set to restore previously saved state.
navController.navigate(it) {

popUpTo(NavigationBase.Dashboard) {
  saveState = true
 }
 // Avoid multiple instances
 launchSingleTop = true
 // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
 restoreState = true
}

Composable view :
@Composable
fun DashboardScreen(
   dashboardViewModel: DashboardScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
   parameters: String? = null,
)

The parameters value is always restored to previous values even when the new values are sent. The restoreState behaviour is also required, since the previous state has to be persisted.
Is there any way to update the arguments, also by keeping the state (tab selection and scroll position of screen) as well?
